# Azure Service Bus Retry Policy's minbackoff doesn't work?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm trying to get a queue's retry logic working and I'm having an issue. the minBackoff variable doesn't seem to actually work. I see in my logs, a message gets received then fails then retries almost immediately. My minBackoff is set to 600 seconds.

Here's the code that sets up the query:

```
 NamespaceManager nsManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        nsManager.Settings.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                                                            maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                                                            maxRetryCount: 3);

        if (!nsManager.QueueExists(queueName))
        {
            nsManager.CreateQueue(queueName);
        }
        else
        {
            nsManager.DeleteQueue(queueName);
            nsManager.CreateQueue(queueName);
        }

        QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);


        client.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                                                         maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600),
                                                         maxRetryCount: 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            UserCreationSubmitted creationMessage = new UserCreationSubmitted()
            {
                CreationStatus = "Step 1",
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UserName = "user number " + i,
                Userid = Guid.NewGuid()
            };

            BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(creationMessage);
            client.Send(message);

        }
```

Here's the code that's not working how I think it should...

```
client.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                                                         maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600),
                                                         maxRetryCount: 3);

        client.OnMessage(message =>
        {

            UserCreationSubmitted msg = message.GetBody<UserCreationSubmitted>();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"Body {msg.UserName}");

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int ranNum = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            if (msg.UserName.Contains(ranNum.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("!!!Error!!!");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
                throw new Exception();
            }
        });
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why the minbackoff and maxbackoff's don't seem to actually work here? Oddly enough the maxRetryCount's working like a trooper so I imagine it's definitely something in my implementation that's causing the others to not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RetryExponential` is used by ASB client for retries when a failure to **receive** a message is happening. In your code, exception is thrown during processing within OnMessage API callback, after the fact that message was received. OnMessage API will [abandon the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_AbandonAsync), causing it to show up right away.

There a few options you could take:

1. Clone a message, set `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` to the delay you want, send it and then complete the original message.
2. Defer your message, but then you can only receive it by `SequenceNumber`. In that case, you could create a new message with that would contain original message sequence number as a payload, schedule the new message and send it. That way you'd have the delivery count on the original message have an accurate count.

Ideally, would be nice to abandon a message with a timespan, but that's not possible with the current API.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful